# Regex to capture in multiline works on regex101.com but not in PowerShell

Tags: regex, powershell, parsing, newline, select-string

This is the regex I am using `code (?m)^.*(10(?:\.\d+){3}\/\d+)\s.*\s(\d+).*$`
It is suppose to catch subnet IP and last 4 digits from the line. One exception being if there is only the subnet IP directly followed by new line, then the capture should continue in next line.

Example data:

`*>   10.118.130.98/32 172.17.128.161             0 65000 4809 23 8705 8705 8705 8705 i
*>   10.118.130.102/32
                      172.17.128.161                         0 65000 4809 23 285 i`

Capture group 1 should contain 10.118.130.98/32 and 10.118.130.102/32 and capture group 2 should contain 8705 and 285. This works well on regex101.com however in PowerShell it catches only the first line[image].

Comment: your data - both the input and the desired output - is BADLY  garbled. please, add code formatting around it so that it becomes readable ... and usable for testing.

Comment: Are you sure this isn't just because you are missing the `-Pattern` operator on the `Select-String` method? e.g. `$file | Select-String -Pattern '(.*/..)(\n)'`

Comment: Once you have time to test out my suggestion, please drop a comment below my answer, will you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest reading the file in as a single text variable, not line by line, using `-Raw`, then use a regex to find lines that only contain an IP-like string followed with a port number and line breaks, and remove those linebreaks in those locations:

```
(Get-Content $file -Raw) -replace '(?m)^(\d+(?:\.\d+){3}/\d+)[\r\n]+', '$1' | Set-Content $file
```

**Pattern details**

- `(?m)` - MULTILINE modifier option
- `^` - start of a line
- `(\d+(?:\.\d+){3}/\d+)` - Group 1: 1+ digits and then 3 repetitions of a dot and 1+ digits, then `/` and 1+ digits
- `[\r\n]+` - 1 or more CR or LF symbols.

The `$1` is a placeholder containing Group 1 value.

Comment: This is what I tried
(Get-Content 'D:\BGP.txt' -Raw) -replace '(?m)^(\d+(?:\.\d+){3}/\d+)[\r\n]+', '$1' | Set-Content .\test.txt
Result is not good:`code
*>   10.118.130.98/32 172.17.128.161                    4809 23 8705 8705 8705 8705 i
*>   10.118.130.102/32
                      172.17.128.161                         0 65000 4809 23 285 i`

Comment: @JozefTrubac Yes, and? Did it work as expected? I have two lines after this: `10.118.130.98/32 172.17.128.161                         0 65000 4809 23 8705` and `10.118.130.102/32                   172.17.128.161                         0 65000 4809 23 285`

Comment: @JozefTrubac So, you also get two lines, and isn't that expected?  If your file looks different from what you showed in the question please update the question, do not use comments

Comment: if I run this in PowerShell it does not return anything so I guess the regex does not work in PowerShell?
`code(Get-Content 'D:\BGP.txt' -Raw) | Select-String '(?m)^(\d+(?:\.\d+){3}/\d+)[\r\n]+'`

Comment: @JozefTrubac It works in PS because I used to test it in Powershell. `(Get-Content 'D:\BGP.txt' -Raw) -replace '(?m)^(\d+(?:\.\d+){3}/\d+)[\r\n]+', '$1'` displays the changed file contents on screen. Please make sure you run the tests on the right file. Do not use `Select-String`. Use my code.

Comment: OK it works fine. I am sorry this was my mistake. I was running the regex in the part of my code where the input data were differently formatted. Thanks a lot guys. Big respect for finding time to help newbies like me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203334/discussion-between-jozef-trubac-and-wiktor-stribizew).